# Using Enum Class to define members in class

Tags: c++, class, enums, enumeration

For an assignment I'm working on, I have to create enum classes and use them to define members of another class. The enum classes are as follows:

```
enum class Ball_colors {
    red,
    blue,
    yellow,
    green
};

enum class Ball_sizes {
    small,
    medium,
    large
};
```

The class, called "ball", represents a ball of a certain color and size. The default constructor for ball is supposed to randomly select a color and size, and I'm supposed to have parameterized constructor, and functions to get size or color, but I have absolutely no clue how to use enum classes, especially not within other classes. I'm not even certain I've defined the classes correctly. How do I use enum classes within another class, and how can I randomly select something from an enum class?

Comment: what have you done so far and why it doesn't work? Note that SO is not "do my homework" site.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you use the name of the enum class just as you'd use the name of any other ordinary class, e. g.

```
Ball_colors m_color;
```

as class member. However, as colours and sizes are that closely related to the ball itself, I'd nest the definition into the `Ball` class. Then you can drop the prefix as well:

```
class Ball
{
    enum class Color { /*...*/ };
    enum class Size { /* ... */ };

    Color m_color;
    Size m_size;
};
```

And I'd drop the plural from the name, it doesn't look that elegant if you specify a member type in plural that only can represent a single value...

If you need to use the enums outside, you can address them as

```
Ball::Color::red
```

Now every enum entry gets a specific value, starting from 0 for first one and each further one getting increased by one (unless you explicitly provide values to some or all entries). You then can use a random number generator to produce a value in the appropriate range and cast that value back to the enum, e. g.:

```
class Ball
{
    static inline std::mt19937 s_generator { std::random_device()() };
    template <typename T>
    static T get()
    {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<std::underlying_type_t<T>> d
        (
            0, static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<T>>(T::Max) - 1
        );
        return static_cast<T>(d(s_generator));
    }
public:
    Ball()
        : m_color(get<Color>()),
          m_size(get<Size>())
    { }
};
```

Above assumes you added a sentinel value `Max` to both enums (after all other entries); alternatively, you can pass the maximum legal value to the template function as well, then you don't have to specify the template parameter either:

```
template <typename T>
static T get(T max)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::underlying_type_t<T>> d
    (
        0, static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<T>>(max)
    );
    return static_cast<T>(d(s_generator));
}

Ball()
    : m_color(get(Color::green))
    // ...
```

But you'll have keep an eye at that second location for possibly being adapted if you add further values to the enum!

Answer (score 0):

Just have something like:

```
struct Ball
{
    Ball_colors color = Ball_colors::red;
    Ball_sizes size = Ball_sizes::small;

    Ball(Ball_colors color, Ball_sizes size) : color(color), size(size) {}
};
```

Comment: OP is asking for random color and random size. However, thats rather orthogonal and could make a second question perhaps

Comment: ...or lets say you rolled dice to pick `red` and `small`, then the requirements are met ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: I indeed drop the random part which seems to be the second problem of OP and should be a second question IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can define data members of a class of a type of a enum class the same way as you define other data members of a class.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum class Ball_colors {
    red,
    blue,
    yellow,
    green
};

enum class Ball_sizes {
    small,
    medium,
    large
};

class Ball
{
private:
    Ball_colors color = Ball_colors::red;
    Ball_sizes size = Ball_sizes::small;

public:
    Ball() = default;
    Ball( Ball_colors color, Ball_sizes size ) : color( color ), size( size )
    {
    }

    std::string to_string() const
    {
        const char *string_colors[] = { "red", "blue", "yellow", "green" };
        const char *string_sizes[]  = { "small", "medium", "large" };

        std::string s( "The ball is " );
        return s + string_sizes[static_cast<size_t>( size )] + 
               " and " + string_colors[static_cast<size_t>( color )] + ".";
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Ball ball1;

    std::cout << ball1.to_string() << '\n';

    Ball ball2( Ball_colors::blue, Ball_sizes::large );

    std::cout << ball2.to_string() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
The ball is small and red.
The ball is large and blue.
```